# What does a file with name ! mean?

Tags: linux, pbs

My computer (RedHat 6 Linux) has recently created some empty files with the following name:

```
!
```

Yes, a single exclamation mark.  I am wondering what, in anything, in Linux will create files of this name?  Perhaps more likely though it is associated with some recent (failed) batches that I've been trying to run on my local high performance computing system.  For reference, I use PBS to submit jobs to the high performance computing system.

I use tcsh

Comment: Looks like it could be a tcsh `>! filename` redirect run with the wrong shell.

Comment: I am using tcsh.  I will mention that in my question.  I have been having problems with using `>!`, I just switched to `>>` and allowed the stuff in my file to accumulate.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: could you clarify what you mean by "run with the wrong shell."?  Does that mean that what I had written for tcsh what possibly getting read with a bash shell once I submitted it to my local high performance computing system?

Comment: Not quite clear to me on what system the files ate being created, but yes, sounds like that could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have pbs run your program with a specific shell, you just need to add the command line option `-S /bin/tcsh` (or a different path if your tcsh isn't in /bin/.

You can also add this line to your script:

```
#PBS -S /bin/tcsh
```